# alternative to collect in spark sq for getting list o map of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Basically is very general my question, everybody tell dont use collect in spark, mainly when you want a huge dataframe, becasue you can get an error in dirver by memory, but in a lot cases the only one way of getting data from a dataframe to a List o Map in "Real mode" is with collect, this is contradictory and I would like to know which alternatives we have in spark.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouln't need to have your data in list or map. You can deal with your DF, filter, map or whatever you need with it, and then write it

Comment: so in general you just don't need your data to be loaded in memory of driver process , main use cases are save data into csv, json or into database directly from executors. Collect should be avoided because it is extremely expensive and you don't really need it if it is not a special corner case

Comment: Yes I know but for example; We have a dataframe with a serie of fields in this one, which one are used for partitions in parquet files. Now I want make a reprocess of the files in parquet, but due to the architecture of the company we can not do override, only append(I know WTF!! but we can not change it), therefore we need first all fields of partition, for building a list with the path which one we will delete. In this case I make something like:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks by the comments and I answer here. Yes I know but for example; We have a dataframe with a serie of fields , which one are used for partitions in parquet files. Now I want make a reprocess of the files in parquet, but due to the architecture of the company we can not do override, only append(I know WTF!! but we can not change it), therefore we need first all fields of partition, for building a list with the paths which one we will delete. In this case I make something like:

```
val twodrop: Array[Row] = df.select(partitionColumns.head, partitionColumns.tail: _*).distinct().collect()

twodrop.map(row => s"$outputPath${partitionColumns.map(colName => s"/$colName=${row.get(row.fieldIndex(colName))}").mkString}").toList
```

I dont know other way to do it, without collect.

Other example, if I want the same for to use the clause isin in sparksql with dataframe, We dont have other way, because this clause isin only accept List. I know we can to do a left_outer join, but I insist, in spark for these cases, there isnt other way get all distributed information in a collection without collect but if you use it, all the documents, books, webs and example say the same thing: dont use collect, ok but them in these cases what can I do?

Thanks.